# How to get resault from function as a response

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my node.js code. There are two inputs on site, one for username and one for the password. When users enter them, function client.logOn gets them. But there is a third step. The user need to enter the code which he gets on his phone. So, when the user enter the username and password, the script will check if they are good, and if they are, the script will ask me for "twoFactorCode" in cmd, and when I enter it there, everything works. But I want users to enter that code on the page. So how can I do it? In cmd, I only need to enter that 5 character code.

```
app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
console.log('i got request');
client.logOn({
    accountName: request.body.uName,
    password: request.body.uPassword,
});});
client.on('loggedOn', () => {                                       
console.log("Logged in");
});
```

Comment: you'll need another api for the same. After the first step you might need to send some token which then client can send back along with the user entered code and then your second API can verify both of them and let user in if both of them are correct

Comment: '/api' is just a random name, script will verify